# When returning graphs getting Index Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some code that should return some graphs based on a Json file.
In the example below i should return 4 graphs, instead it retruns 3 and I get an index Error.

I have no ideia of where the index error is.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:math';

class Graficos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GraficosState createState() => _GraficosState();
}

class _GraficosState extends State<Graficos> {
  List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  int qteMeses = 12;
  var jsonData;
  List<Widget> todosGraficos = List();
  bool primeirociclo = true;
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  List<LinearSales> dados = List();
  List<double> precos = List();
  double menorPreco = 0;
  double maiorPreco = 0;
  var graficos = <Widget>[];
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  var staticTicks;
  var duplicateItems = List<String>();
  var items = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _Carregar();
  }

  Future<String> _Carregar() async {

    primeirociclo = true;
    print('local');
    var response = await _funcaoJson();
    if (response.length != null) {

    }
    return 'ok';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: jsonData == null ?
        Container() :
        ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                    filterSearchResults(value);
                      },
                        controller: editingController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Pesquisa",
                            hintText: "Pesquisa",
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(25.0)))),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: myController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Quantidade de meses',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      child: Text('Gerar Gráfico', style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {

                        qteMeses = int.parse(myController.text);
                        await _funcaoJson();
                      },

                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'].length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  dados.clear();
                  precos.clear();
                    montaGrafico(index);

                    return todosGraficos[index];

                },
              ),

            ]));
  }

void montaGrafico(int index)  {

if (jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'][index]['ranking'] !=null) {
      for (var i = qteMeses; i >= 0; i--) {
        dados.add(
          LinearSales(new DateTime(int.parse(
              ((jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][i]['data_publicacao'])
                  .toString()).split("\/")[2]), int.parse(
              ((jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][i]['data_publicacao'])
                  .toString()).split("\/")[1]), int.parse(
              ((jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][i]['data_publicacao'])
                  .toString()).split("\/")[0])), double.parse(
              (jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][i]['items'][index]['ranking'][0]['preco']
                  .toString()).replaceAll(',', '.'))),
        );

        precos.add(double.parse(
            (jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][i]['items'][index]['ranking'][0]['preco']
                .toString()).replaceAll(',', '.')));
      }
    }

if (jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'][index]['ranking'] !=null) {

    seriesList = _pegaDados(dados);

}
    Widget grafico;


    if (jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'][index]['ranking'] !=null) {

      grafico = Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        child: new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
            seriesList,
            domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
              tickProviderSpec: charts.DayTickProviderSpec(increments: [30]),
            ),
            primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.AxisSpec(
                tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(
                    staticTicks)),
            behaviors: [
              new charts.ChartTitle(
                  jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'][index]['nome_produto'].toString(),
                  behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.top,
                  titleOutsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.start,
                  innerPadding: 18),
              new charts.ChartTitle('Mes',
                  behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                  titleOutsideJustification:
                  charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
              new charts.ChartTitle('Preço',
                  behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
                  titleOutsideJustification:
                  charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
              new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
              new charts.RangeAnnotation([
                new charts.RangeAnnotationSegment(new DateTime(int.parse(
                    ((jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][qteMeses]['data_publicacao'])
                        .toString()).split("\/")[2]), int.parse(
                    ((jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][qteMeses]['data_publicacao'])
                        .toString()).split("\/")[1]), int.parse(
                    ((jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][qteMeses]['data_publicacao'])
                        .toString()).split("\/")[0])),
                    new DateTime.now(),
                    charts.RangeAnnotationAxisType.domain),
                new charts.LineAnnotationSegment(
                    maiorPreco, charts.RangeAnnotationAxisType.measure,
                    endLabel: 'Maior Preco: $maiorPreco',
                    color: charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shade400),
                new charts.LineAnnotationSegment(
                    menorPreco, charts.RangeAnnotationAxisType.measure,
                    startLabel: 'Menor preco: $menorPreco',
                    color: charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shade400),
              ]),
            ]),

      );
    } else {

      grafico = Divider();

    }

    todosGraficos.add(grafico);
    print(todosGraficos.length);

  }

  List<charts.Series<LinearSales, DateTime>> _pegaDados(List<LinearSales> data) {

    menorPreco = precos.reduce(min);
    maiorPreco = precos.reduce(max);


    double tickPreco = (menorPreco - 0.2);
    staticTicks = <charts.TickSpec<double>>[
      new charts.TickSpec(
        tickPreco,
        label: tickPreco.toStringAsPrecision(3),
      ),

      new charts.TickSpec(tickPreco + 0.2),
      new charts.TickSpec(tickPreco + 0.4),
      new charts.TickSpec(tickPreco + 0.6),
      new charts.TickSpec(tickPreco + 0.8),
    ];


    print(data);
    dados = data;
    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Preço',
        displayName: 'Preço',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.mes,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,

      )
    ];
  }

  Future<String> _funcaoJson() async {
    /*var data = await http.get(
        'http://itajuba.myscriptcase.com/scriptcase/devel/conf/grp/Procon/libraries/php/pesquisa_total.php?id=3&meses=$qteMeses&fornecedor_id=23');
*/
    String httpJson = 'http://itajuba.myscriptcase.com/scriptcase/devel/conf/grp/Procon/libraries/php/pesquisa_total.php';

    var response = await http.post(httpJson, body: {
      'id': '3',
      'meses': qteMeses.toString(),
      'fornecedor_id': '23'
    });

    setState(() {
      jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    });

    return 'Sucesso';
  }
  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<String> dummySearchList = List<String>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(duplicateItems);
    if(query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> dummyListData = List<String>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        if(item.contains(query)) {
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(duplicateItems);
      });
    }

  }

}

class LinearSales {
  final DateTime mes;
  final double sales;

  LinearSales(this.mes, this.sales);
}
```

> ```
> I/flutter (32442): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> I/flutter (32442): The following RangeError was thrown building:
> I/flutter (32442): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 8
> I/flutter (32442):
> I/flutter (32442): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> ```

Can someone help me identify where the Index is wrong?

Comment: rewrite your itemcount properties as below `itemCount: jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'].length ?? 0,`
this gonna show nothing if list is empty otherwise you will get an error

Comment: My item count occours before the error, the jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'].length returns me 8, but it seems that jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'][index] have a range of 6. not sure why this is happening if it takes the items lenght to the index.

Comment: it takes null while data receive then you use ?? operator you can replace null to a value ?? 0 means if its null then zero

Answer (score 0):

I foud where the problem was, my back-end guy added 2 more products this month, so when I was in itemCount: jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][0]['items'].length it was 8, but for example itemCount: jsonData['pesquisa_total'][0]['pesquisas'][4]['items'].length it was 6 so there was my index error.